# Problem adding predicates to outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, null, predicate, outer-join

I have been tearing my hair out over this:

```
-- misses nulls
SELECT *
FROM BASE_TABLE TAB1
     FULL JOIN BASE_TABLE TAB2
       USING (ANOTHER_ID)
WHERE (TAB1.ID = 6 OR TAB1.ID IS NULL)
  AND (TAB2.ID = 8 OR TAB2.ID IS NULL);

-- catches nulls
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM BASE_TABLE WHERE ID = 6) TAB1
     FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM BASE_TABLE WHERE ID = 8) TAB2
       USING (ANOTHER_ID);
```

The first query loses rows where the row in one or the other table does not exist.  Why does the first query fail to do an outer join?

I keep thinking I've got it - the WHERE clause is evaluated first, so the 'OR IS NULL' is not applied later - but that doesn't make sense to me because I've successfully applied 'IS NULL' predicates in the past to select rows after the join.

I would like to make the first query work, for performance reasons - does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: I am confused about `USING` - what syntax is that? I cannot find it in any docs, normal SQL uses `ON TAB1.ANOTHER_ID = TAB2.ANOTHER_ID`..?

Comment: @littlegreen An Oracle feature since 9i. It's essentially shorthand for what you wrote.

Comment: @littlegreen, djacobson: when you use `USING (ANOTHER_ID)` it results in only a single column called `ANOTHER_ID` (which cannot be referenced by alias), whereas the `ON` syntax results in both columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query does a join then a filter, the second does a filter then a join.
With an outer join the distinction is important.

You'll understand it with some sample data.

```
create table tab1 (id number, another_id number);
create table tab2 (id number, another_id number);

insert into tab1 values (6,5);
insert into tab2 values (8,5);
insert into tab1 values (1,6);
insert into tab2 values (2,6);

SELECT *
FROM TAB1
     FULL JOIN TAB2 USING (ANOTHER_ID);

     ANOTHER_ID              ID              ID
--------------- --------------- ---------------
           5.00            6.00            8.00
           6.00            1.00            2.00
```

The result set (without the WHERE) shows that the join condition for another_id 6 has been successful. There is no need for the outer join.

When you add the WHERE filter, it filters out the match for 6 since the ids are neither 6,8 nor null. That is, you have used it as a filter predicate not a join predicate.

I believe what you intended was that for TAB1 to join to TAB2 there should be a match on ANOTHER_ID plus the ID should be 6 for TAB1 and 8 for TAB2. That's what is in the second SQL.

The join predicate can also be expressed as

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB1
    FULL JOIN TAB2 ON 
           (TAB1.ANOTHER_ID = TAB2.ANOTHER_ID AND TAB1.ID=6 AND TAB2.ID=8)
```

Comment: This might be it, though I'm sure I've used the WHERE clause to check IS NULL to exclude matches, which implies the IS null check is after the join.  I'll play around with your example.  By the way, I've tried your alternate wording, but when you include a predicate in the ON rather than in the WHERE clause, the optimizer tends to try to join every record without filtering first, which is a performance headache.

Comment: Yes, the predicates in the WHERE clause must be applied after the predicates in a join clause when using an outer join. That's the point. Your requirement is to apply the ID=6/8 condition either before or during the join, so they should not be in the WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. It's a brainteaser allright, but I think I might have it.

In your first query, you are full-joining the table to itself on the key ANOTHER_ID.

When two joined tables are the same, it doesn't matter whether you do a full join, inner join, left join or right join: the result is the same. Because your key, ANOTHER_ID, always either exists or doesn't exist in both tables. There are no cases in which one table has a value for ANOTHER_ID that is not found in the other table, and as such there are no cases where either TAB1.ANOTHER_ID or TAB2.ANOTHER_ID would end up NULL. So you are actually just doing a self-inner-join on ANOTHER_ID.

Now I don't know the content of your ID column, but I imagine that it is always filled with some value. So after your self-inner-join, the resulting ID columns will always be filled with something. Perhaps not 6 or 8, but also not NULL. In the absence of NULL values, your WHERE query translates to `WHERE TAB1.ID = 6 AND TAB2.ID = 8` which leaves only the correct combinations and nothing else.

In contrast, in your second query, you are defining subsets of ID=6 and ID=8 and full-joining those subsets to one another. Subset 1 contains certain occurrences of ANOTHER_ID not present in subset 2, and vice versa. So now there is ground for a FULL JOIN because certain rows will not be joined to other rows, leaving NULL values in TAB1.ID or TAB2.ID which you can detect.

I think your first query can be adjusted by changing your WHERE clause to: `WHERE TAB1.ID IN (6,8) AND TAB2.ID IN (6,8)`. That will however give a different result as your second query, and I think also a certain amount of duplicate rows. And I also don't think it will be faster.

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with the fact that it's a self-join vs. a join of 2 separate tables.  But I will try your example and maybe I will see the light.